# Notification automatically opens up without any click

Tags: android, android-notifications

Notification opens up as soon as it is posted, not needing any action from the user.

Here is my code:

```
private void sendNotification(String message,String title,String id,String book) {
    smLocalStore=new SMLocalStore(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Log.i("id:",id);
    intent.putExtra("id",id);
    intent.putExtra("val","1");
    intent.putExtra("book",book);
    int requestCode = 0;
    //notification sending
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_lau)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(x, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove following line from your code:

```
.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
```

[Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)) says:

> `setFullScreenIntent(PendingIntent intent, boolean highPriority)`
>
> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status bar.

Comment: For multiple notifications how to show a single notification icon in the status bar